# Application with LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag set getting less virtual memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, operating-system, 32bit-64bit, large-address-aware

I have a 32-bit application consisting one EXE and multiple DLLs. The EXE has been built with `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag set. So I expect on a 64-bit OS I should get 4 GB of user address space. But on some 64-bit Win 7 systems I am getting only 2 GB of user address space.

The physical memory is 8 GB if that matters. What could be reason for this behavior?

Comment: Can you try `DUMPBIN /HEADERS` on your executable just to confirm the flag is set?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I confirmed with `DUMPBIN /HEADERS`, It says application can handle large address.

Comment: I am using `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` to find the total virtual memory, if that matters.

Comment: There is no known way to defeat /LAA.  This is either a bug in your code, IsWow64Process() isn't that easy.  Or an environmental problem, something like anti-malware jumps to mind.

Comment: Are you sure that your 2Gb limitation isn't coming from actually being on a 32 bit system?  (We have a 32 bit that uses this same flag, and have never seen a problem like yours since 64 bits systems came out.  That doesn't mean your problem isn't real).   There may also be a Virtual Memory per process configuration somewhere.

Comment: @IraBaxter: Nope, its a 64 bit system.

Comment: Is it the case that Windows has heuristically decided to run the app in 32bit compatibility-mode? Check out the end of this [**link**](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html) for a quick way to determine and forcefully disable compatibility-mode on this app.

Comment: I deleted my non-answer, glazed over important details. Has the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag been cleared? According to this MS documentation that would cause the limit to be 2GB on 64bit systems. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#memory_limits

Comment: To clarify, is it _some_ or _all_ Win7 64 bit systems you tried on?

Comment: @AlexanderGessler: Only on some systems. Most of the systems its getting 4GB.

Comment: Since you have totally, 8 GiB available, have you tried allocating/committing 3 GiB of RAM or more? It might be that `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` is wrong ...

Answer (score 3):

After browsing through MSDN, I found the following:

On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366770(v=vs.85).aspx (the page for `MEMORYSTATUSEX` which is used by `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx) ) the description for `ullTotalVirtual` is:

> this value is approximately 2 GB for most 32-bit processes on an x86 processor and approximately 3 GB for 32-bit processes that are large address aware running on a system with 4-gigabyte tuning enabled.

The 4GB tuning page is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613473(v=vs.85).aspx and it says something like:

> On 64-bit editions of Windows, 32-bit applications marked with the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag have 4 GB of address space available.
>
> Itanium editions of Windows Server 2003:  Prior to SP1, 32-bit processes have only 2 GB of address space available.

Also, the memory limits page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx#memory_limits) can come handy if you want to determine the total memory your system supports.

However the real useful information comes from Mark Russinowich's blog: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx

> While 4GB is the licensed limit for 32-bit client SKUs, the effective limit is actually lower and dependent on the system's chipset and connected devices. The reason is that the physical address map includes not only RAM, but device memory as well, and x86 and x64 systems map all device memory below the 4GB address boundary to remain compatible with 32-bit operating systems that don't know how to handle addresses larger than 4GB.

So the conclusion is that yes, this might depend on the configuration of the system. Maybe you can complete your question with a table, with the amount of the memory you get on each system and some important system configuration settings, and we might discover a pattern in this case.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that an Application has a whole has to be large Adress aware - so that pointers are to be treated as unsigned.

If however on "some" system some of your used DLL is not large adressaware this renders your whole program not large address aware.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/22/10065933.aspx

Comment: How should that work? The exe uses 32 bit pointers until a DLL is loaded (which can be hours later) and then all pointers are changed to be 31 bit only? And following that link , Raymond Chen clearly says the switch has no effect on a DLL.

Comment: The dlls do not have linker options. So how they can be "not large address aware" ???