# LARGEADRESSAWARE only gives me 2.5GB

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am compiling an application with the /LARGEADRESSAWARE switch set, but when running and looking at the taskmanager, the application allocates max. ca. 2.5GB then it fails with memory allocation errors. Is this correct behaviour?

- 32 Bit Application (of course)
- 64 Bit OS / Win10
- Compiled Visual Studio Comunity 2017
- There is enough OS memory available (16GB)

In the taskmanager i should see the full 4GB. MSDN states "4 GB with IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE set" for a 32 Bit process running under a 64 Bit OS  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#memory_limits)

This is the linker command line (with some paths stripped)

> /OUT:"xxx.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"xxx.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE
>   /LARGEADDRESSAWARE /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH:NO /PGD:"xxx.pgd"
>   /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
>   /ManifestFile:"xxx.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO
>   /LIBPATH:"xxx" /TLBID:1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application with LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag set getting less virtual memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424236/application-with-largeaddressaware-flag-set-getting-less-virtual-memory)

Comment: Task Manager does not show the commit size by default.  Both working set and private bytes are meaningless numbers when you have out-of-memory problems.  And Task Manager is the worst possible memory profiler you could find :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even checking the commit size in Task Manager cannot reveal all possible sources of an OutOfMemoryException, although it was a good guess by Hans Passant.

Here are some examples were it does not work:

- run an application and *reserve* 3.5 GB of memory instead of *committing* it. Very likely that you get an OutOfMemoryException as well, but the commit size column in Task Manager will not help you. In that case you'll need a tool to display the Reserved Size, e.g. [VMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap.aspx) or [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) (use "virtual size" there, which is reserved + committed)
- write the following very simple .NET program:

  ```
  class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          byte[] b = new byte[2*1024*1024*1000];
      }
  }
  ```

  In that case, you neither have committed nor reserved memory that could help you identify the source of the OutOfMemoryException. Here we have a problem of virtual memory fragmentation.

Some [debuggers can help you analyzing OutOfMemoryExceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142607/how-to-use-windbg-to-track-down-net-out-of-memory-exceptions).

Screenshot of a program that reserved 2 GB and has only 12 MB committed:

[image: Reserved memory in VMMap]

[image: Reserved in Process Explorer]

Answer (score 2):

[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) gave a useful answer in his comment. I did not check **'Commit Size**', i checked the private bytes and commit size in the task manager shows some 3.5GB memory usage when allocations begin to fail. Thanks!